# Open standard iPhone photo library application from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, photo

I need to open photo library from my iPhone app just like standard iPhone Camera application does. Is it possible?

I don't want picking-style interface of UIImagePickerController - it has unnecessary controls like "Use" and "Cancel" buttons and does not have full photo library viewing functionality - zooming and sliding between photos etc. My goal is to navigate user to the photo library for viewing photos (with full functionality of viewing photos) and - when user has finished - return to my app - just like standard Camera application does when you preview last-taken photos.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "Three20"-framework has such a photo library.
http://github.com/facebook/three20

http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTPhotoViewController.h

Answer (score 0):

http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/

Answer (score 0):

seem like that it is possible to open only 1 photo using UIImagePickerController, can not open multiple photos.